# find paths with specific length combined with nodes with specific degree neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I am trying to write a query to find all nodes with outdegree X and only return the paths that contains those nodes when path length is equal to Y

If I want to get only nodes with outdegree X I use the following Cypher query

```
MATCH (s:URL)-[r:VISITED*]->(t:URL) 
WITH s, count(t) as degreeout 
WHERE 73 in s.job_id and degreeout <4 
return s, degreeout
```

If I want to get only paths with length = X I use the following query

```
MATCH p=(s:URL)-[r:VISITED*]->(t:URL)
WHERE length(p)=7
return p
```

I tried the combine the previous two queries in the following query

```
MATCH (s:URL)-[r:VISITED*]->(t:URL)
WITH s, COLLECT(DISTINCT id(s)) as matched, count(t) as degreeout
WHERE 73 in s.job_id and degreeout <4
MATCH p=(s2:URL)-[r:VISITED*]-(t2:URL)
WHERE id(s2) in matched and length(p) >=1
RETURN p
```

Whenever I execute the query, the machine keeps processing and then I get an error no enough memory.

It seems like there is an infinite loop !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're just interested in traversing the relationship an exact number of times you can include that in the path expression:

```
MATCH p=(s:URL)-[r:VISITED*7]->(t:URL)
return p
```

In general you should avoid doing traversals of unlimited length, i.e.  `:VISITED*`. If you want to keep the depth variable because it's unknown it's good practice to set a max. value, i.e. `:VISITED*..7`.

If I understood correctly, your original query can be adjusted, just be setting the variable length to 7 in the path:

```
MATCH (s:URL)-[r:VISITED*7]->(t:URL) 
WITH s, count(t) as degreeout 
WHERE 73 in s.job_id and degreeout <4 
return s, degreeout
```

You should see some performance improvement because now paths of length > 7 will be excluded from the results and they won't be traversed. Again, always avoid unlimited depth traversals unless there is a really good reason for it and you have enough computer resources + time for the query to complete.

Regarding performance best practices, this query will still not perform very well, since it's forcing a graph scan to find the start node. I understand the nodes labeled URL contain a property `job_id` of type Array because of the `in` operator? Neo4j needs to read all URL nodes and their properties, then scan through those arrays just to find the start node.

I would recommend changing your data model to use schema indexes based on an exact property value. Example:

```
(j:Job {job_id: 73})-[:SOMETHING?]->(u:URL {...})
```

We would also add a schema index:

```
CREATE INDEX ON :Job(job_id)
```

Then you can query like this:

```
MATCH (j:Job {job_id: 73})-[:SOMETHING?]->(s:URL)-[r:VISITED*7]->(t:URL) 
WITH s, count(t) as degreeout 
WHERE degreeout <4 
return s, degreeout
```

Comment: I label the starting node as STARTING_URL ... so the starting node will have two labels "URL" and "STARTING_URL"

Comment: Regarding the job_id I can't have it as an int property value. I should have it as an array property. I don't think that this way (j:Job {job_id: 73}) (property as dictionary) would enable me to handle the job_id attribute as an array  ... !??

Comment: The problem with that approach is that locating a node by an array property is not efficient, since it won't use any indexes and Neo4j will have to scan all nodes with matching labels. If you have n job_ids for each STARTING_URL, then you can probably create one node for each job_id and have a relationship to the STARTING_URL as I tried to explain in the last section of my answer. This approach would take more advantage of Neo4j's graph performance capabilities.

Comment: I did create the JOB node as u suggested and changed the design. I just have a question now. How I can return all paths with length >=3 and the same time exclude all nodes with outdegree > 10?? How I can do this in a cypher query...??

Comment: You can add a minimum depth: MATCH (j:Job {job_id: 73})-[:SOMETHING?]->(s:URL)-[r:VISITED*3..]->(t:URL) WITH s, count(t) as degreeout WHERE degreeout <11 return s, degreeout

Comment: Hello @I.el-sayed . If you think the answer is correct, can you please indicate this answer as the correct answer so that others know? Otherwise let me know what might be missing. Thanks.